# Why isn't my py scoreboard saving overall score

Tags: python

I'm currently creating a dice game, that takes a score each round for 3 players,
but it appears to be resetting the players total score each round.

the issue appears to be isolated to the scoreboard section of the code
def update_scoreboard(self, round_number, player, points):

```
    if round_number in self.scoreboard:
        # Accumulate points from previous rounds
        previous_round_score = self.scoreboard[round_number - 1].get(player, 0)
        self.scoreboard[round_number][player] = points + previous_round_score

        # Update round score
        self.round_scores[player] = points

        # Update overall score
        self.overall_scores[player] += points

    # If it's the first round, initialize the player's score
    else:
        self.scoreboard[round_number] = {player: points}
        self.round_scores[player] = points
        self.overall_scores[player] = points
```

Am I missing something obvious?

I've tried altering all other portions of the code to get a better resolution, introducing brand new variables to handle overall score and nothing appears to be working

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and stepping through your code? You might be able to find where the logic goes wrong yourself.

Comment: A few print statements should reveal what is happening eg print(previous_round_score). There is not enough info provided to know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: To start with I would certainly try changing your `else:` to `elif round_number==1:` (assuming `round_number` starts from 1, which it appears to), and see if that changes the behaviour. It might not fix the problem but if the code is erroneously thinking it is the first round and for this reason is resetting scores this should prevent that.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your code right now, it isn't really clear what `self.scoreboard` actually stores. Is it the overall score, or something else? It seems to serve the purpose of the overall score in the first part of the code, where it accumulates the points from each round, but then there's `self.overall_score`, which should be that. Another thing is that separating the code into different cases for the first and subsequent rounds isn't necessary. From what I can see, the code in your `else` block does exactly the same as the code in the main `if` block - `sets self.scoreboard[round_number][player]` to the `points` added to the previous score, sets `self.round_scores` to `points`, and then adds `points` to `overall_score`. Because `overall_score` and `previous_round_score` will be 0 until the first round is calculated, the same results are achieved.

In order to help you debug, but also to help overall, I think that altering how you store your information might help. I feel like `self.scoreboard` could be used more effectively. Most of the information that are you keep over the rounds, such as the scores for each round, and the overall score at each round, could be in fact stored here. You could change the dictionary structure so it stores, per player, the overall score and the score for that round at each point. You could store this all in one dictionary per round, like this:

`{"player1":{"overall_score":43,"round_score":5},"player2":{"overall_score":57,"round_score":3}}`

to keep track of the overall and round score after each round for each player, simply accessing them using, for example, `self.scoreboard[round_number][player]["overall_score"]` in order to find the overall score of player 2 after round `round_number` (which would give 57 in my example as long as `round_number` is correct and `player` was equal to `"player2"`). You might use different keys to access each player's data, (as I don't know what type you're using for `player`) but it would still work.

This would then change your code to be:

```
#Initialise dictionary for this round and player
self.scoreboard[round_number][player] = {"overall_score":0,"round_score":0}

# Update round score
self.scoreboard[round_number][player]["round_score"] = points

# Update overall score
previous_overall_score = 0
if round_number != 1:
    previous_overall_score = self.scoreboard[round_number - 1][player]["overall_score"]
self.scoreboard[round_number][player]["overall_score"] = previous_overall_score + points
```

When reading this code, you may notice two things:

1. I have not included the code relating to what was previously `self.scoreboard[round_number][player]`, since I am unsure what it is supposed to represent. If that could be clarified, I could also assist you with that.
2. This code *is* dependent on the round number, even though I said it shouldn't. This is because of the way I have written the new version of the dictionary structure. Your code did not need the if statement, but this one does. It is of course a small sacrifice (if it is even a sacrifice at all, I don't see anything wrong with `if` statements) for being able to compact the information.

After all the rounds have been calculated, `self.scoreboard` will be a nice dictionary containing all the scores obtained by every player at each round, along with the total score at that point.